# OnRowClick in a GridView not taking over button clicks?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, onclick

I have a C#/ASP.net GridView that is contained within a UserControl.  The way I have it now, gridview will have an onrowclick attribute added on as follows:

```
protected void _gridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
  e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(this.GridView, "EditRow$" + e.Row.RowIndex);
}
```

However, I get an invalid postback error due to EventValidation when this click event occurs.  Also, I have buttons on the row that use GridViewRowCommands to redirect to other pages.  Unfortunately, I can't get both to work together either (the RowCommand function never gets run).

For example, this is the handler I would use:

```
protected void _gridView_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
   if (e.CommandName.ToString() == "EditRow" && e.CommandArgument.ToString() == "0")
      Response.Redirect(anotherURL);
   if (e.CommandName.ToString() == "BACK" && e.CommandArgument.ToString() == "0")
      Response.Redirect(thisURL);
}
```

And this is a button I use on the row:

```
<asp:Button ID="_AddButton" runat="server" CommandName="BACK" CommandArgument="0" Text="Add" />
```

Ideally, the row-onclick will use this GridViewRowCommands as well so I can have the handling of the redirection all in one place.  However, I'm not sure how to go about this.  Any suggestions as to a better approach?

Thanks for your continued support!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how to add comments so an answer will have to do.

Are you saying it's not hitting the RowCommand method what-so-ever? If not I would consider wiring the event in the following manner via the Page Init.

```
GridView1.OnRowCommand += _gridView_RowCommand
```

Comment: Thanks.  I tried that, but the RowCommand is still never occurring.  Currently the eventValidation problem is occurring before it has the chance to run, but even before I had that problem (in some old version - don't remember how it got fixed) the button click events were not working.

Answer (score 0):

In the page directive, add the following:

```
EnableEventValidation="false";
```

Should work fine after that. That's probably the simplest way around your problem.

You could also do something like this too:

```
e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = "javascript:onRowClick('" + e.Row.RowIndex + "');";
```

And in the ASPX, add a JavaScript function:

```
onRowClick = function(rowIndex){
   __doPostBack("<%=dataGridView1.UniqueID%>", rowIndex);
}
```

And lastly, in your code behind, add the RaisePostBackEvent override:

```
protected override void RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler source, string eventArgument)
{
    base.RaisePostBackEvent(source, eventArgument);

    int rowIndex = ToInt32.Parse(eventArgument);
    if (source is DataGridView)
    {
        if (source == dataGridView1)
        {
             GridViewRow row = dataGridView1.Rows[rowIndex];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I was hoping to avoid disabling EventValidation.  Will this code still work without it?

Answer (score 0):

I handled a similar problem by appending a client side click event to each row.

1. Add OnRowDataBound event handler to grid view.

   ```
   OnRowDataBound="GridView_RowDataBound
   ```
2. In the OnRowDataBound event handler, add an "onclick" attribute that grabs the primary key for the record and passes that along in the redirect URL.

   ```
   protected void GridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
       {
           int id = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[0].Text);
           e.Row.Attributes["onclick"] = string.Format("javascript: window.location = 'Edit.aspx?id={0}'", id);
       }
   }
   ```

Note that this assumes that the first column of your grid view is your primary key.